# Can't import python modules?

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to use Scrapy.org's scrapy thingy, but I cant seem to be able to import it after installing it. 
[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2zjl.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Error code:

```
C:\Users\Hentaiware\Desktop>pip show scrapy
Name: Scrapy
Version: 1.5.1
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
Home-page: https://scrapy.org
Author: Scrapy developers
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\hentaiware\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires: parsel, six, w3lib, queuelib, Twisted, PyDispatcher, lxml, cssselect, pyOpenSSL, service-identity
Required-by:
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\Hentaiware\Desktop>python idek.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idek.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scrapy
ImportError: No module named scrapy

C:\Users\Hentaiware\Desktop>
```

Where python:

```
C:\Users\Hentaiware>where python
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe
C:\Users\Hentaiware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
C:\Python\python.exe
C:\Users\Hentaiware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\Hentaiware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

Comment: Never post images of code or errors. Copy and paste (and format) instead.

Comment: added the error text

Comment: Can you add the output of `where python`?

Comment: added where python output

Comment: From your `where python` you have at least three different versions of the Python interpreter installed. When you run `python` you're getting the 2.7 version. It's likely that you don't have `pip` installed for Python 2.7, and the only `pip` being found is for Python 3.6, where it is included by default. You should consider using 3.6, which may require altering your program. If your code is written in 2.7 and you strongly wish to continue using it, upgrading to 2.7.9 will also give you `pip` for free. Otherwise, look into installing `pip` in the 2.7.5 version you have now.